# Try/Catch: Moving catches to separate function?

Tags: c#, exception

```
try
{ 
    myInfo = getMyInfoFromAPI(); //stubbed
}
catch (JsonSerializationException exception)
{
    // special handling and logging
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   // special handling and logging
}
```

This kind of code in my opinion is quite long and could be broken into separate functions. Is it possible to move the catches each into finally block where it can see if there is anything to catch?

```
try
{ 
    myInfo = getMyInfoFromAPI(); //stubbed
}
finally {
    handleJsonException();
    handleException();
}


public void handleJsonException() {
    catch (JsonSerializationException exception)
    {
        // special handling and logging
    }
}
public void handleException() {
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        // special handling and logging
    }
}
```

Is this possible or even good practice? The reason I'm curious if we can move the catches into new functions is the lines of code can become quite long and unreadable for one given function.

Answer (score 4):

finally cannot catch exception.

I recommend to use like this.

```
try
{ 
    myInfo = getMyInfoFromAPI(); //stubbed
}
catch (JsonSerializationException ex)
{
    handleJsonException(ex);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   handleException(ex);
}

public void handleJsonException(JsonSerializationException ex) {
    // special handling and logging
}

public void handleException(Exception ex) {
    // special handling and logging
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `finally` is not to catch exception, it will be called irrespective of  `Exception` is thrown or not, use `finally` for clean-up purposes (disposing of objects).

If you want to make the `catch` block modular based on the `Exception` type then you can do something like -

```cs
try
{
    // Some Code
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    if (exception is InvalidOperationException operationException)
    {
        MethodCall(operationException);
    }
    else if (exception is JsonSerializationException  jsonSerializationException)
    {
        AnotherMethodCall(jsonSerializationException);
    }
    
    // If want to throw the exception further.
    throw;
}
```